# auto type deduction with uniform initialisation syntax c++11 vs c++17

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, auto, uniform-initialization

I was trying to test auto type deduction. Both Scott Meyers (Effective modern C++) and Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Programming Language mention that doing

`auto val {10};`

will deduce val to be of type "initialisation list".

I read that this was changed in C++17 so that if there is only one element in the list, then auto will deduce to a type of that element instead.

However, I tested this with recent gcc (v10) and clang (V11) compilers by explicitly specifying the C++11 standard and I didn't see the behaviour expected

```
auto A {1.0};
std::cout << typeid(A).name();
```

prints "d" to screen

whereas

```
auto A={1.0};
std::cout << typeid(A).name();
```

prints "St16initializer_listIdE" to screen.

This is the same regardless of whether I specity

```
gcc -std=c++11
```

or

```
gcc -std=c++17
```

and similarly for clang.

I understand that it was changed in C++17, but why then do I not see the "old" behaviour? Or am I misunderstanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper that introduced this change for C++17—https://wg21.link/n3922—has the statement:

> Direction from EWG is that we consider this a defect in C++14.

If something is a defect, that means that the paper is retroactively applied, so future compilers compiling for a previous standard will exhibit the *new* behavior. This is why you don't see the old behavior.

If you compile with an older compiler from before this defect was fixed, you can see that the deduced type is `std::initializer_list<double>`: https://godbolt.org/z/GrnrTE .
Whereas if you change the compiler to a newer version (e.g. g++ 10.2), you can see that the deduced type is `double`: https://godbolt.org/z/r5G945

Answer (score 1):

With

```
auto A { 1.0 };
```

you have [*direct initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), and will use the type of the enclosed expression to deduce the type.

It's essentially equivalent to

```
auto A = 1.0;
```

On the other hand

```
auto A = { 1.0 };
```

is [*copy list initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), and when used in conjunction with `auto`:

> A special exception is made for [type deduction using the keyword `auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts), which deduces any braced-init-list as [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) in copy-list-initialization.

Comment: Good information, wrong question. This question is about why the compiler doesn't seem to be doing it that way.